# struggle with `[[no_unique_address]]`

Tags: c++, c++20

I get strange `sizeof()` results with `[[no_unique_address]]` in g++ 13.2.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<bool T>
struct B
{
    struct Dummy {};

    int *a; // swap position with <below placemark>
    // In this position, results are "16" and "40".
    
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<T, Dummy, size_t> y;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<T, Dummy, size_t> x;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<T, Dummy, size_t> h;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<T, Dummy, size_t> w;
    
    // <below placemark>
    // In this position, results are "8" and "40".
    
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(B<true>) << "\n";
    cout << sizeof(B<false>) << "\n";
}
```

The result is

```
16
40
```

but if you change `int *a;` to position after the `[[no_unique_address]]` lines, you get

```
8
40
```

Also, with only one `[[no_unique_address]]` line, and with the member pointer variable before, the results are correct:

```
8
16
```

I read documentation about `[[no_unique_address]]` but I don't something specific.

Why this happens?

Comment: does the result change if you replace int& a by int* a ?

Comment: @alfC No, but I change the sample code with a pointer. It is better.

Comment: You just broke CPPInsights https://cppinsights.io/s/f821f452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unsatisfying answer is that `[[no_unique_address]]` is only a *hint* to the compiler that it may overlap the members in the struct, it does not guarantee any particular layout. (From the standard: “the circumstances under which the object has zero size are implementation defined”).

There are a few ways in which the compiler is restricted in how it can allocated field offsets. One is that field offsets must be nondecreasing. Another is that fields of the same type *must* have distinct offsets (otherwise, pointers to different fields would not be distinguishable — this isn't an issue for pointers to fields of *different* types because strict aliasing rules forbid those comparisons).

That means that if you defined a struct with 4 Dummy structs, that struct will still take 4 bytes because the fields must be assigned different offsets.

That means concretely that while the compiler can assign `a` and `y` the same offset, it must assign `x`, `h` and `w` distinct offsets. This can be shown as follows:

```
struct B
{
    struct Dummy {};
    int &a;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy y;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy x;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy h;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy w;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "size: " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
    cout << "offset a: " << offsetof(B, a) << "\n";
    cout << "offset y: " << offsetof(B, y) << "\n";
    cout << "offset x: " << offsetof(B, x) << "\n";
    cout << "offset h: " << offsetof(B, h) << "\n";
    cout << "offset w: " << offsetof(B, w) << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
size: 16
offset a: 0
offset y: 0
offset x: 8
offset h: 9
offset w: 10
```

Apparently, the compiler decides that `x`'s offset must not overlap with `a` *or* `y`. It's not clear to me if that's a compiler quirk or there is a good reason for it (it's worth noting that GCC and Clang behave the same way). The total size of 16 is then the result of rounding the size up from 11 bytes to a multiple of 8.

There seem to be two ways to avoid this. One is to put the empty fields first. Another is to make sure they have different types:

```
struct B
{
    struct Dummy1 {};
    struct Dummy2 {};
    struct Dummy3 {};
    struct Dummy4 {};
    int &a;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy1 y;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy2 x;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy3 h;
    [[no_unique_address]] Dummy4 w;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "size: " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
    cout << "offset a: " << offsetof(B, a) << "\n";
    cout << "offset y: " <<offsetof(B, y) << "\n";
    cout << "offset x: " <<offsetof(B, x) << "\n";
    cout << "offset h: " <<offsetof(B, h) << "\n";
    cout << "offset w: " <<offsetof(B, w) << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
size: 8
offset a: 0
offset y: 0
offset x: 0
offset h: 0
offset w: 0
```

I think the simplest solution is to put all potentially-empty fields at the top of the struct.

Comment: Is it coincidental that having the empty objects first was what happened effectively when the only way to do this was to use the empty-base-class optimization?

Answer (score 3):

When `T` is `true:`

- `sizeof(a)` is 8.
- `sizeof(x)`... are equal to `sizeof(Dummy)` and are 1 each.
- `x`, `y`, `h`, `w` can overlap each other and their sum size can be  1 till 4, let it be 1.
- `sizeof(B<true>)` is `sizeof(a)` + `sizeof(x) ...` + pad(7) is 8 + 1 + 7 is 16.

When you move `a` at the bottom:

- `x`, `y`, `h`, `w` allow to be overlapped by `a`. Since they are empty, they are completely overlapped by `a`.
- `sizeof(B<true>)` is overlapped(0) + `sizeof(a)` is 8.

Why the first case does not really overlap `x`, `y`, `h`, `w` with the zero size at the class storage end. Consider an array `B<true> arr[2]`. `[[no_unique_address]]` member allows to be overlapped by a next class member but does not allow to be overlapped by `arr[1].a`. If `sizeof(B<true>)` was 8, `arr[1].a` would overlap `arr[0].w`, that was not allowed.

Comment: Your answer is not compliant with the result you get when members are `a` and `y` only (comment `x`, `h`, `w` out). In that case `y` is after `a` but `sizeof(B<true>) == 8`.